# Display all calendar events in android programmatically

Tags: android, calendar

I want to get all the calendar events (from google calendar or android phone).Is there any sample code ?Can Anybody help me ? I used code from
**[This Blog post](http://jimblackler.net/blog/wp-trackback.php?p=151)** .
but it shows "Unfortunately, app has stopped".getting Null pointer exception.

**1. Main Activity**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ReadCalendar.readCalendar(this);        
    }   
}
```

**2. ReadCalendar class**

```
public class ReadCalendar 
{
    static Cursor cursor;

    public static void readCalendar(Context context) {
    
    ContentResolver contentResolver = context.getContentResolver();

    // Fetch a list of all calendars synced with the device, their display names and whether the
    // user has them selected for display.
    
    final Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(Uri.parse("content://calendar/calendars"),
            (new String[] { "_id", "displayName", "selected" }), null, null, null);


    HashSet<String> calendarIds = new HashSet<String>();
    
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

        final String _id = cursor.getString(0);
        final String displayName = cursor.getString(1);
        final Boolean selected = !cursor.getString(2).equals("0");
        
        System.out.println("Id: " + _id + " Display Name: " + displayName + " Selected: " + selected);
        calendarIds.add(_id);
    }
    
    // For each calendar, display all the events from the previous week to the end of next week.        
    for (String id : calendarIds) {
        Uri.Builder builder = Uri.parse("content://calendar/instances/when").buildUpon();
        long now = new Date().getTime();
        ContentUris.appendId(builder, now - DateUtils.WEEK_IN_MILLIS);
        ContentUris.appendId(builder, now + DateUtils.WEEK_IN_MILLIS);

        Cursor eventCursor = contentResolver.query(builder.build(),
                new String[] { "title", "begin", "end", "allDay"}, "Calendars._id=" + id,
                null, "startDay ASC, startMinute ASC"); 


        while (eventCursor.moveToNext()) {
            final String title = eventCursor.getString(0);
            final Date begin = new Date(eventCursor.getLong(1));
            final Date end = new Date(eventCursor.getLong(2));
            final Boolean allDay = !eventCursor.getString(3).equals("0");
            
            System.out.println("Title: " + title + " Begin: " + begin + " End: " + end +
                    " All Day: " + allDay);
        }
    }
}
```

3. Added permission in manifest file also

Comment: This way you are very unlikely to get help from people around here. Can you please add some example code to you question? Something you tried so far?

Comment: Formatting correction.

Comment: How can I get the Event notes, attendees, etc...